# Show plot points with the same coordinates in the same InfoWindow()

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Im using google map api to plot a list of events. Events have the coordinates to the venue where the event is held. Most venues have more then one event. How do I show all events with the same coordinates in one info window.

```
var locations = [
  ['event number 3', 40.750504, -73.993439],
  ['event number 2', 40.750504, -73.993439],
  ['event number 1', 40.750504, -73.993439],
];

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 1,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.7484, -73.9857),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  });

  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  var marker, i;
  for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
      map: map
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
      return function() {
        infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
      }
    })(marker, i));
  }
```

Example [jsfiddle.net/uu2qkr10/](http://jsfiddle.net/uu2qkr10/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the coordinates of the marker before creating a new one.  If the new one has the same coordinates as one of the existing markers, add its information to the existing marker's infowindow.

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/bot1mxr2/)

**code snippet:**

```js
var gmarkers = [];

function initialize() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 7,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.7484, -73.9857),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  });

  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  var j;
  for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]);
    for (j = 0; j < gmarkers.length; j++) {
      if (latlng.equals(gmarkers[j].getPosition())) {
        gmarkers[j].IWcontent += "<hr>" + locations[i][0];
        break;
      }
    }
    if (i == 0 || j == gmarkers.length) {
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latlng,
        map: map,
        IWcontent: locations[i][0]
      });
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(evt) {
        infowindow.setContent(this.IWcontent);
        infowindow.open(map, this);
      });
      gmarkers.push(marker);
    }
  }
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
var locations = [
  ['event number 3', 40.750504, -73.993439],
  ['event number 2', 40.750504, -73.993439],
  ['event number 1', 40.750504, -73.993439],
  ['event number 4', 41.750504, -73.993439]
];
```

```css
#map {
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a contradiction by design.

How about a different symbol for this type of venue, and in the popup a list of events ordered by date?

Comment: What do you mean by different symbol? That's basically what I want the the events to list inside of the google.maps.InfoWindow()

Answer (score 0):

Just a little tip. If the number of elements in the vector `locations` is not too high I would try to get to find the lines with similar coordinate with a nested iteration and these would build a linked list of events to be displayed in a single infowindow connected to a single location. Brutal but effective.

Answer (score 0):

Just change your latitude and longitude values. Don't use the same value for multiple time. Otherwise all the markers placed in same position. So you can view only one.

and your should remove `,` at the end of location

try this,

```
 var locations = [
  ['event number 3', 40.750504, -73.993439],
  ['event number 2', 47.750504, -73.993439],
  ['event number 1', 50.750504, -73.993439]
];

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 1,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.7484, -73.9857),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  });

  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  var marker, i;
  for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
      map: map
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
      return function() {
        infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
      }
    })(marker, i));
  }
```

Comment: One plot point would be fine. This is more of a question of how to get events with the same coordinates into the same info window.